# Python: how to set the global log level properly?

Tags: python, oop, logging, architecture, python-logging

I'm setting the log level based on a configuration. Currently I call `Settings()` from the inside of `Logger`, but I'd like **to pass** it instead **or set it globally** - for all loggers.

I do not want to call `getLogger(name, debug=Settings().isDebugMode())`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
class Logger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

        debug_mode = Settings().isDebugMode()
        if debug_mode:
            self.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

    def getLogger(name):
        logging.setLoggerClass(Logger)
        return logging.getLogger(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to achieve this would be to only set a level on the root logger and keep all other loggers as `NOTSET`. This will have the effect that every logger works as if they had the level that is set on root. You can read about the mechanics of how that works in the documentation of [`setLevel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel).

Here is what that would look like in code:

```
import logging

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # set this based on your Settings().isDebugMode()

logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger')
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(sh)

logger.debug('this will print')
root.setLevel(logging.INFO) # change level of all loggers (global log level)
logger.debug('this will not print')
```